# Rails 3.2.2 installation error following Hartl RoR Tutorial, "can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-lion

I've been following Hartl's RoR tutorial and have hit an error in the sequence to set up Rails.  I'm running OS X Lion 10.7.3.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2#sec:rubygems

I've installed Git as instructed.  I've installed RVM (1.10.3) in order to update Ruby to 1.9.3 (1.9.3p125 is the version displayed when I type "$ruby -v").

I have updated RubyGems to 1.8.17, the version fixed for the tutorial.

I used vi to create a gem configuration file, per the tutorial.  I may have screwed this up somehow since I'm not familiar with vi, but this was the last thing that I did before hitting this error:

```
jboggan$ gem install rails -v 3.2.2
/Users/jboggan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3 p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:183:in `merge': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
    from /Users/jboggan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:183:in `initialize'
    from /Users/jboggan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/jboggan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/jboggan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Users/jboggan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/gem:25:in `<main>'
```

I'd appreciate any input into getting past this.  I've searched but been unable to find anyone else having this problem.  This is my first post on SO, so please tell me if I need to provide more info, fix my phrasing, or do something to make the question more intelligible.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I believe I've figured it out.  Related to this question:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742771/no-rails-commands-will-run)

I think I just screwed something up in the .gemrc file while editing with Vim.  I deleted it and the install is back on track.

Answer (score 0):

I incorrectly edited my .gemrc file during the tutorial.  I deleted the offending file and was able to install Rails 3.2.2 normally.  See answer from [No rails commands will run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742771/no-rails-commands-will-run) .